# Bring focus to a batch started browser window

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script that launches two Chrome windows. I want to focus the first one when it launches and then the second one.

`"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen --app=https://www.youtube.com/login`

//focus this window

...

`"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen --https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions`

//focus this window

...

I want to be able to run this in a cmd context, so a powershell or batch script would be great.

Comment: What you have posted would only open two MsEdge windows if you've overwritten your Google Chrome application executable with your msedge executable, and renamed it `chrome.exe`!

Comment: My script checks to see if Chrome is installed. If it doesn't find one, it picks MS edge. That part is not relevant here.

Comment: I suppose there shall be the problems on Chrome windows manipulation by process id. So  I recommend to use API-functions  **FindWindow**, **SetForegroundWindow** by Powershell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell scripting. Is there a function to tell the two Chrome windows apart?

Comment: `Get-Process` would probably be your best bet, short of simply storing the PID in a variable when you start it up.

Comment: I think Chrome Process ID is useless for windows manipulating. Use window's handle instead. If you are not familiar with Powershell there are many examples to manipulate windows by **VBscript**. For example: **CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate("Subscriptions - Youtube")**